# Why is my SSL Certificate on Azure App Service not working correctly?

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I used to run one of my websites (EyeDentity.Online) from a Windows VM on Azure. I had an SSL Certificate in IIS up to run it and all was well in the world.

Since I moved the Website to the Azure App Service and installed the SSL Certificate in Azure whenever I go to the Website for the first time in a browser session it tells me that the certificate is invalid.

It appears to quote the standard AzureWebsites.NET even though my certificate is bound to my website

How can I get this warning to go away as it may be scaring away users!

[image]
[image: When I click "Show Certificate" I see the following.]

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I have exactly the same issue (using asp.net core 2.0 / issue appeared after I deleted the original app and created a new one with the same name/config hosted in a different region)

Answer (score 0):

Your cert is for azurewebsites.net and not EyeDentity.Online. You should get a wildcard cert for your domain name:

> *.azurewebsites.net should be:  *.eyedentity.online

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/#1-get-an-ssl-certificate

> "Before requesting an SSL certificate you must first determine which
>   domain names will be secured by the certificate. This will determine
>   what type of certificate you must obtain. If you just need to secure a
>   single domain name such as contoso.com or www.contoso.com a basic
>   certificate is sufficient. If you need to secure multiple domain
>   names, such as contoso.com, www.contoso.com, and mail.contoso.com,
>   then you can get a wildcard certificate, or a certificate with Subject
>   Alternate Name (subjectAltName)."

Comment: The certificate installed is for EyeDentity.online not azure websites

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. You must be on Standard or Premium level to bind to cert
2. Check SSL bindings section of Custom Domains and SSL blade to make sure you've
   bound the domain to the right cert.

[image]

The description of the problem sounds like number 2 here. If you haven't changed this, then it will bind by default to the azurewebsites cert and not yours.

Some docs here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: I have gone through that guide and its setup as described, including what is in your image. Still warning me about the certificate though

Comment: When you say what's in my image, you don't mean *exactly* what's in my image, right? You see your host name and certificate selected, not the "choose..." defaults shown? Sorry if I'm asking obvious questions, but such is debugging... ;-)

Comment: Hehe, not exact I was referring to that part on the settings. I have selected the correct host name and certificate.

Comment: That's what I figured, but remote debugging means asking painfully obvious questions... If you've uploaded the cert and selected it, then I'm not sure why it's not using it. At this point I'd probably try testing both the SSL Types just for completeness. You may need to file a support ticket.